# Construct a type that changes the base class of a mixin

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to be able to change the type of the inner-most type of a mixin. A sketch is shown below:

```
struct PointTypeA {
    double x,y;
};

struct PointTypeB {
    double x,y,z;
};

template<class Base>
class MyMixin1 : public Base {
public:
    double someProperty;
};

template<class Base>
class MyMixin2 : public Base {
public:
    double someProperty;
};

// how do we automatically construct MyMixin2<MyMixin1<TNewInside> > from MyMixin2<MyMixin1<PointTypeA> >
// template <typename T, typename TNewInside>
// ChangedType ChangeInsideType(T object) {
//     return ChangedType(object);
// }

int main() {
    typedef MyMixin2<MyMixin1<PointTypeA> > Mixed12A;
    Mixed12A mixed12A;

    //MyMixin2<MyMixin1<PointTypeB> > mixed12B = ChangeInsideType<Mixed12AType, PointTypeB>(mixed12A);
    return 0;
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the inner template parameter can be done using this:

```
template <class ToReplace, class With>
struct replace_inner {
    using type = With;  
};

template <template <class> class Outer, class Inner, class With>
struct replace_inner<Outer<Inner>, With> {
    using type = Outer<typename replace_inner<Inner, With>::type>;
};

template <class ToReplace, class With>
using replace_inner_t = typename replace_inner<ToReplace,With>::type;
```

We use it like so:

```
using replaced = replace_inner_t<MyMixin1<MyMixin2<PointTypeA>>, PointTypeB>;
static_assert(
    std::is_same<replaced, MyMixin1<MyMixin2<PointTypeB>>>::value, "wat"
);
```

Then you just need to write the converting constructors between the point types and mixins with different template parameters.

Comment: Amazing, thanks. Now I just have to cancel my weekend plans to study what is going on :)

Comment: @DavidDoria Essentially it recurses down the outer types until it runs out, then replaces the inner one with the one you specified.

Comment: I think I'm getting close. For the 3 blocks of code: 1) This is the base case of the recursion that switches the inner type when it gets to a non-templated class. 2) This is a partially specialized version of replace_inner where the first template parameter is a template-template parameter (which is the place where our mixins will appear as Outer). Inside of this "using type" we have the recursion, calling replace_inner on Inner itself. 3) A convenience typedef. 
My confusion is with the specialization - how can it have 3 parameters when the original replace_inner only has 2?

Comment: @DavidDoria That's all correct! Specializations can have more template parameters than the primary template (what you call the "base case"), so long as they can be deduced from the specialization arguments (the `<Outer<Inner>, With>`).

Comment: So how does it know what we mean by Outer? In the "top level" call, Outer could be MyMixin1<> while Inner is MyMixin2<PointTypeA>, or Outer could be MyMixin1<MyMixin2<>> and Inner just PointTypeA - both seem to fit the pattern Outer<Inner>?

Comment: @DavidDoria The `template <class> class Outer` parameter is called a *template template parameter*. That will only analyse the top-level template, so `MyMixin1<MyMixin2<>>` isn't an option.